# Does every shape of "lower-bounded width" contain a shape of constant width?

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry

Suppose we have a convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose width along every axis is at least 1. Can we take a subset of its points which has width exactly 1 on every axis?

For example, the unit square contains a Reuleaux triangle:

[image: reuleaux triangle inscribed in square]

I suspect the answer here is no, but I haven't come up with any obvious counterexamples. It's also possible that the answer is yes when $n=2$, but counterexamples can be found when $n=3$ (or possibly only at higher $n$).

Comment: An interesting generalization here would be surrounding the "largest" solid of constant width that could fit into any convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose dimensions along each axis are at least $1$. The answers below suggest that the number is less than $1$

Comment: Oh, interesting! I can prove that one can always get width $0.5$ (there’s always a circle at least that large in the shape), though I’d guess that’s far from optimal.

Comment: Perhaps a cool place to start would be answering it for the equilateral triangle

Comment: For the equilateral triangle, a Reuleaux triangle of width $(3+\sqrt{3})/6\approx 0.7887$ is optimal. (One can show that if the width $w$ were greater than this, one would need to have three points in three corner triangles of height $1-w$, and that any such three points will have a pairwise distance greater than $w$ among them.)

Comment: I can show that every such convex set contains a circle of diameter $1/\phi\approx0.618$, by using a little less simplistic argument, though I think the actual largest circle that can be found in every set of diameter at least 1 is somewhat larger still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, solved it.

The counterexample turns out to be quite simple: an equilateral triangle! First, a little geometric reasoning should make it clear that the shortest an equilateral triangle of height $1$ gets along any axis is the altitude from a vertex to the midpoint of the opposite side, as shown below:

[image]

For this and the other two such axes on the triangle, for our constant-width subset to have diameter $1$ it must contain both the vertex and the point on the opposite face. So the curve of constant width passes through all three vertices of the triangle. But any two of these vertices are too far apart! So no such subset exists.

Comment: Interesting. What necessitates that it must pass through all vertices?

Comment: For each vertex $V$, it must pass through that vertex; the altitude from $V$ is of length $1$, and without $V$ no two vertices are $1$ apart along that axis

Answer (score 0):

The equilateral triangle is a counter example. The equilateral triangle with height $1$ (i.e., width $1$ in the vertical axis) has side length $2/\sqrt{3}$.

[image: Width One Triangle]

This set has width larger than one along any axis: given any axis, the at least one line along that axis and through one of the vertices passes through the triangle and the segment inside the triangle has length at least one.

The area of this triangle is $1/\sqrt{3} \approx 0.577$.

The [Blaschke–Lebesgue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke%E2%80%93Lebesgue_theorem) states that the Reuleaux triangle has the least area of all sets of constant width. The [area of the Reuleax triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle#Extremal_measures) is $\frac{\pi - \sqrt{3}}{2} \approx .705$.

So the area required for a set of constant width is too large to be contained in the equilateral triangle.